# Iterate an operation considering multiple columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, loops, iteration, pandas-groupby, return-value

I have a DataFrame link as Pic1:

To get Desired output i need to use below criteria
Criteria:if ****Distance** >85kms** in at least **2 Routes** from **Cities column** as base then return Ok; else Nok

Needed output to be saved in Shtout workbook

[image: Input]
[image: Desired Output]

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name="Map")

import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path2)
wb.create_sheet("output")
ShtOut = wb["output"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could groupby cities then check the sum of distances over 85

```
df.groupby('Cities')['Distance'].apply(lambda x: 'Ok' if sum(x>85) >1 else 'Nok').reset_index(name='Result')
```

Comment: getting below error
("'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'",)

Comment: Perhpas your distance column is a string not an integer